# Javascript, String: Getting a Javascript var as a string

Tags: javascript, string

Because using .toString() for null vars doesn't work, and I can't be checking each and every one of these in my particular application.

I know this is a stupidly simple problem with an answer that literally must be staring me in the face right now.

Comment: what would you expect to see in the string if `null` or `undefined` was passed in, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-concatenation route is to use the *String()* constructor:

```
var str = new String(myVar);  // returns string object
var str = String(myVar);      // returns string value
```

Of course, `var str = "" + myVar;` is shorter and easier.  Be aware that all the methods here will transform a variable with a value of *null* into `"null"`.  If you want to get around that, you can use `||` to set a default when a variable's value is "falsey" like null:

```
var str = myVar || "";
```

Just so long as you know that *0* and *false* would also result in `""` here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
var str = '' + someVar;
```

Comment: @Hamster Sure it's hackish, so stick it in a function to make it cleaner. Then you can make it smarter if you end up with new kinds of variables to deal with.

Comment: +1 - short and simple, works just like `String(myVar)`, however, an edge-case might be when a form value is itself `"null"`. These are the kind of bugs that can make life hell 1 month down the line :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
var str = (variable || "");
//or
(variable || "").toString();
```

Of course you'll get this for `false`, `undefined` and so on, too, but it will be an empty string and not `"null"`

Answer (score 1):

`String(null)` returns `"null"`, which may cause problems if a form field's value is itself `null`. How about a simple wrapper function instead?

```
function toString(v) {
    if(v == null || v == undefined) {
        return "";
    }
    return String(v);
}
```

Only `null`, `undefined`, and empty strings should return the empty string. All other falsy values  including the integer `0` will return something else. Some tests,

```
> toString(null)
""
> toString(undefined)
""
> toString(false)
"false"
> toString(0)
"0"
> toString(NaN)
"NaN"
> toString("")
""
```

Answer (score 0):

How about ... ?

`var theVarAsString = "" + oldVar;`